# How to make a double linked-list in javascript + html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class called `listaDoble`, in a Javascript document.
And I have another HTML document with a text field and 4 buttons: `Next`, `Back`, `New`.
When I press the `New` button I put, `onmouseclick="lista= newListaDoble();"`, but then I lose the reference to the object. Some help?

Comment: I think I don't get what you're trying to do with those buttons... Are you trying to preserve references among HTML pages? If so, you could just simply use the browser's history to go back. If not, please explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your javascript variable as

```
 var lista = null;
```

before you assign value to it. Not in onclick handler but in the body of the page.